# go to a page only by clicking on an image on another page

Tags: php, session

I want to restrict access on `write.php` page so that it is possible only by clicking on an specific image on another page (index.php).
I'm trying with ssession variable, but it only works if browser is just started. In this case you cannot go directly (via address bar) on `write.php` and it's ok.
But once the browser is started and load `index.php` you can open `write.php` in a new tab without clicking on the image, which is not the idea.
Anny suggestion.

index.php

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['pass']=1405;
?>

<a href='write.php'><img id="imgL" src="img/05.png" alt="img"></a>
```

write.php

```
session_start();
if (!($_SESSION['pass'] == 1405))
{
    header('Location: index.php');
}
```

Comment: And check referrer - it must be your index.php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make use of **`$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`** instead of Sessions.

**index.php**

```
<a href='write.php'>Click</a>
```

**write.php**

```
<?php
if(basename($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']=='index.php'))
{
    //do your thing...!
}
else
{
echo "You came from somewhere !!! You are not allowed!";
}
```

Comment: Shankar, thanks a lot, I will try, and as I see it will work.